# How to get vscode markdown to highlight OCaml code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, ocaml

I cannot get my OCaml code block highlight in vscode markdown files. The default syntax to specify language is `language` where you can put the name of the language to get highlighted. I cannot find the documentation for the keywords for OCaml. `.ml` files do have highlights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding markdown, adding `ml` to the backtick fence should be enough, since [VSCode uses `highlight.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70456058/6309), and this [library does list its supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md).

With VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2021), you can even specify [triple-backtick code blocks with more than just a language identifier in the info string](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157793).

See [PR 157947: "Allow markdown code blocks to contain data after language id"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/157947). Released to [VSCode insiders today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).
(From [issue 157793](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157793))

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [OCaml Platform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ocamllabs.ocaml-platform) extension.

Comment: I believe you may misunderstood the question. The OP appears not to need to get syntax highlighting in OCaml source files, but rather wants highlighting in markdown files.