# Where can I find the list of supported languages for markdown preview code fence syntax highlight in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used markdown preview feature in vscode a lot.

I figured out the code fence syntax highlighting language support in markdown preview panel is different from the list of vscode supported language. I tried to google this, but can not find any useful information.

For instance, `shell` in markdown preview code fence is for terminal syntax instead of shellscript/bash and it does not exist in vscode language support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can tell (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138855#issuecomment-991301667), VSCode uses the highlight.js . . . library? (unclear to me)

There is a list of supported languages on their github page:
https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md